# Adding a Form Folder with a local role in Plone 3

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

If I assign a user all available local roles using the sharing tab, they still aren't able to add a Form Folder. How do I work around this?

I'm using Plone 3.1.7 and PloneFormGen 1.5.2

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're able to add a Form folder as admin (in the location you're testing it out as that normal user)? Just to make sure the product is installed correctly.

Another option is: how did you configure the addable types? Did you restrict that somehow?

Comment: Yes, I can add a form as admin and I haven't configured addable types.

Comment: Well, "it should just work", so I'm down to "making sure".

- I've made the mistake once of giving a user all sorts of rights on the main document of a folder instead of on the folder itself.

- Can the user add other items in the folder just fine?

- There's a 1.5.4 out.  You could try installing that one. The infamous "perhaps a reinstall helps".

Sorry for not having a sure-fire solution; I'm down to guessing.